# How to instantiate a Google Map from within a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

Right now the map loads with the code below, but I would like to be able too interact with it programmatically (to set my location via a call to .setMyLocationEnabled(), for example).  Everything I have attempted thus far results in a crash.  This is in a fragment managed from the MainActivity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapFrag extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap map;

public MapFrag(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}
}
```

The XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="***.fragment">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

How can I instantiate the GoogleMap in the fragment in order to interact with it?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are loading a fragment in a fragment here. Nested fragments are very tricky, and only work on API Level 17+ or via the fragments backport in the `android-support-v4` library.

Instead, have your activity load the `MapFragment` (or `SupportMapFragment` if you are using the fragments backport). If you want more business logic in that fragment, subclass `MapFragment` (or `SupportMapFragment` if you are using the fragments backport) and have the activity load the subclass.

If you have a couple of years of Android experience and are really sure that you want to use nested fragments, you need to decide which fragments implementation you are going to use, and synchronize them. Right now, your Java code has a `Fragment` that is using the fragments backport (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`), but you are trying to load `MapFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`.

Also, either delete the `MapFrag` constructor or chain to the superclass constructor.